# Force return type of all functions in a class in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to build a class in typescript where, all the functions have to return a promise without explicity declaring the return type of each function In other words, adding a non async function to the class should throw an error i.e

```
class myClass {
    errfunc() { // This should throw a compiler error
        return 1;
    }

    correctfunc() {
        return new Promise((res) => res('success')) // This should work correctly
    }
}
```

I have tried the following

```
interface PromiseDictionary {
    [key: string]: () => Promise<any>;
}
class myClass implements PromiseDictionary {
    a() {
        return new Promise(res => res('success'))
    };
}
```

But it throws the following error:

```
Class 'myClass' incorrectly implements interface 'PromiseDictionary'.
Index signature is missing in type 'myClass'.`
```

How can this be done?

Comment: add `async` to every function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can say the class implements a record with the keys of the current class of type `() => Promise<any>` this will force all public members to be functions that return a `Promise`:

```
class myClass implements Record<keyof myClass, () => Promise<unknown>> {
    errfunc() { // This should throw a compiler error
        return 1;
    }

    correctfunc() {
        return new Promise((res) => res('success')) // This should work correctly
    }
}
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEC2CeBhcVoEtYAcQFNY4DsAXGAJR2AHsAnAEwB4BrHeSgMziRQgBpoAKAJTQAvAD5oABWqVYaCDnpgC8MRIDeAKGg7oOatTYBXAsCHR10APRXoAFQAW86BAeUjIWtCIOZAd2gwaCosNFxqPQMabV1Y6hwiI2oCaABGAG4YnQBfTSzgmnjgImNTcy1YuISklIIcAOlZeRx+fniIYXFodv4AcggjYGAcKF7BYRt7JxhXd09oPxpGAoMKIhB4fNzsoA)

This will force all functions to have no parameters, to allow functions with parameters you can use

```
class myClass implements Record<keyof myClass, (...a: never[]) => Promise<unknown>> {
    errfunc() { // This should throw a compiler error
        return 1;
    }

    correctfunc(a: string) {
        return new Promise((res) => res('success')) // This should work correctly
    }
}
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEC2CeBhcVoEtYAcQFNY4DsAXGAJR2AHsAnAEwB4BrHeSgMziRQgBpoAKAHTCwALmgEcANxzUA2gF0AlNAC8APmgAFapVhoIOegFcCjApQDuBdZoDeAKGjPos6m1PB+Ku9AD0ftAAKgAWBtAQIZTGILTQRCG6ltBg0FRYaLjUrtS61E4uhdQ4RMbUBNAAjADcBc4Avg51aTTFwEQeBF5iEUTUaAQA5j7NRSVlFZLJOnoGOPz8xRAqGtBL-ADkEMbAwDhQG0oqAcFhMJHRsdCWNIwtuRREIPDNjfVAA)

Answer (score 0):

you should add a return type of promise your method

```
class myClass {
    async errfunc(): Promise<appropriate_data_type/any> =>  { // This should throw a compiler error
        return 1;
    }

    async correctfunc(): Promise<appropriate_data_type/any>  {
        return new Promise((res) => res('success')) // This should work correctly
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated the question. What needs to happen is that adding any function other than an async function in the class should throw an error.